# MySQL Query: SUM counting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, count, sum, left-join

I have a query that generates a profit and loss statement for our customers, but I am having a problem with joining the orders table causing the SUM to be multiplied by the number of expense entries.

I have the following tables:

- user_report_categories, "urc", which is category titles for users who report
- user_report_expenses, "ure", which is individual expenses, with an "adjusted_cost" and a "expense_date".  These may or may not have orders associated with them, but in this case we are only concerned with expenses linked to orders.  There may be multiple expenses per order, but each expenses/order will always be in different categories.
- orders, "o", which has an "agreed_fee", "balance", and of course, an "id"

The report needs to have one column per month within a user selected date range, with calculated values in the cells.

The query as is follows:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(m, '%m')), 1, 3) AS month,
COUNT(o.id) AS "# of Orders",
ROUND(SUM(o.agreed_fee) - SUM(o.balance), 2) AS "Total Income",
ROUND(SUM(ure.adjusted_cost), 2) AS "Total Expenses",
ROUND(SUM(o.agreed_fee) - SUM(o.balance) - SUM(ure.adjusted_cost), 2) AS "Profit & Loss",
"" AS "",
ROUND(SUM(ure.adjusted_cost) / COUNT(ure.id), 2) AS "% of Expenses per Order",
ROUND((SUM(o.agreed_fee) - SUM(o.balance)) / COUNT(ure.id), 2) AS "Average Fee per Order",
ROUND(((SUM(o.agreed_fee) - SUM(o.balance)) / COUNT(ure.id)) - (SUM(ure.adjusted_cost) / COUNT(ure.id)), 2) AS "Average P/L per Order"

FROM ( 
    SELECT y, m FROM 
    (SELECT YEAR('2016-01-01') y) years, 
    (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) months
) ym 

LEFT JOIN user_report_categories AS urc ON urc.user_id = 48 
LEFT JOIN user_report_entries AS ure ON ure.user_category_id = urc.id AND YEAR(ure.expense_date) = y AND MONTH(ure.expense_date) = m 
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.id = ure.order_id 
WHERE urc.report_type = 'expense' AND urc.user_id = 48  AND ure.order_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY y, m
```

and the result:

```
month,# of Orders,Total Income,Total Expenses,Profit & Loss,,% of Expenses per Order,Average Fee per Order,Average P/L per Order
Jan,387,36400.00,5921.17,30478.83,,15.30,94.06,78.76
Feb,559,55327.50,8165.12,47162.38,,14.61,98.98,84.37
Mar,736,74785.00,10261.07,64523.93,,13.94,101.61,87.67
```

I determined that orders were being multiplied by the number of expenses by adding the order id to the group-by

```
GROUP BY y, m, o.id
```

and see the new result having multiple orders per row:

```
month,# of Orders,Total Income,Total Expenses,Profit & Loss,,% of Expenses per Order,Average Fee per Order,Average P/L per Order
Jan,6,360.00,31.95,328.05,,5.33,60.00,54.68
Jan,1,0.00,30.24,-30.24,,30.24,0.00,-30.24
Jan,6,1200.00,141.74,1058.26,,23.62,200.00,176.38
Jan,6,540.00,160.97,379.03,,26.83,90.00,63.17
Jan,6,540.00,98.77,441.23,,16.46,90.00,73.54
Jan,8,720.00,167.44,552.56,,20.93,90.00,69.07
... etc ...
```

Alternatively, when I remove the o.id from the group-by and instead change the # of orders line to count distinct:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS "# of Orders",
```

I get correct values for the # of orders, but of course the other values which SUM orders table values are still incorrect because of the duplication.

```
month,# of Orders,Total Income,Total Expenses,Profit & Loss,,% of Expenses per Order,Average Fee per Order,Average P/L per Order
Jan,71,36400.00,5921.17,30478.83,,15.30,94.06,78.76
Feb,105,55327.50,8165.12,47162.38,,14.61,98.98,84.37
Mar,146,74785.00,10261.07,64523.93,,13.94,101.61,87.67
```

I am not sure if I am even taking a good approach to this, but doing this generation in one query is a huge advantage for me so I am trying to piece it together.  How can I get it to SUM order-table values on distinct order IDs, or otherwise correct the query to calculate correctly?  Thanks!

---

Answer

@Sal kicked me off and the final query I ended with follows.  I think it covers all the problems that came up in the comments too.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(m, '%m')), 1, 3) AS month,
orders AS "# of Orders",
round(total_income,2) AS "Total Income",
round(total_expenses,2) AS "Total Expenses",
round(total_income-total_expenses,2) AS "Profit & Loss",
"" AS "",
round(total_expenses/orders,2) AS "% of Expenses per Order",
round(total_income/orders,2) AS "Average Fee per Order",
round( (total_income/orders)-(total_expenses/orders), 2) AS "Average P/L per Order"

        FROM ( 
            SELECT m, 
            (SELECT count(o.id)
                FROM orders o
                WHERE year(o.datetime) = ym.y
                AND month(o.datetime) = ym.m AND o.user_id = 48
                AND o.cancelled = 0
            ) AS orders,
            (SELECT IFNULL(sum(o.agreed_fee - o.balance), 0)
                FROM orders AS o
                WHERE year(o.datetime) = ym.y
                AND month(o.datetime) = ym.m 
                AND o.user_id = 48
                AND o.cancelled = 0
            ) AS total_income,
            (SELECT IFNULL(sum(ure.adjusted_cost),0)
                FROM user_report_entries AS ure
                INNER JOIN user_report_categories AS urc ON urc.id = ure.user_category_id
                  WHERE year(ure.expense_date) = ym.y
                AND month(ure.expense_date) = ym.m 
                AND urc.user_id = 48  AND urc.id NOT IN (6287) ) AS total_expenses
            FROM ( SELECT 2017 y, 1 m  UNION SELECT 2017, 2 UNION SELECT 2017, 3
            ) ym

            GROUP BY y, m
        ) t
```

Comment: `COUNT(o.id)` with `GROUP BY`,  `COUNT(o.id)` without `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` are different from each other, and will return different values. Based on the queries above, it is not easy to understand what is the expected output so it'd be great to add some more info (i.e. table schemas and/or output) or just an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: I sense a problem: `user_report_entries` have costs and are related to orders. Let's say you have an order with an `agreed_fee` of 100. For this order you have a report entry of 2016-01 with an `adjusted_cost` of 40 and another report entry of 2016-02 with an `adjusted_cost` of 50. So which of the two months do you calculate with which `agreed_fee`? You need an algorithm for this (maybe calculate an order and all its report entries only in the month of the first or last report entry or in the month of the order date).

Comment: @DarshanMehta those were some of the things I tried and their result.  I need the query to behave in such a way that each order is only counted or summed once, even if there are multiple expenses per the order.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You're right, that is a big flaw in my query.  Since orders represent income they should be used in the month they are executed, and expenses in the month they were created.  I'm going to have to do some more figuring on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you find this useful:

```
SELECT substring( monthname( str_to_date(m,'%m'), 1, 3) month
     , orders "# of Orders"
     , round(total_income,2) "Total Income"
     , round(total_expenses,2) "Total Expenses"
     , round(total_income-total_expenses,2) "Profit & Loss"
     , round(total_expenses/orders,2) "% of Expenses per Order"
     , round(total_income/orders,2) "Average Fee per Order"
     , round( (total_income/orders)-(total_expenses/orders), 2) "Average P/L per Order"
  FROM ( SELECT m
              , ( SELECT count(distinct ure.order_id)
                    FROM user_report_entries ure
                    WHERE year(ure.expense_date) = ym.y
                      AND month(ure.expense_date) = ym.m
                ) orders
              , ( SELECT sum(o.agreed_fee - o.balance)
                    FROM user_report_entries ure
                      INNER JOIN orders o
                        ON o.id = ure.order_id             
                    WHERE year(ure.expense_date) = ym.y
                      AND month(ure.expense_date) = ym.m 
                ) total_income
              , sum(ure.adjusted_cost) total_expenses
           FROM ( SELECT 2016 y, 1 m
                  UNION
                  SELECT 2016, 2
                  UNION
                  SELECT 2016, 3
                ) ym
             LEFT JOIN user_report_entries ure
               ON    year(ure.expense_date) = ym.y
                 AND month(ure.expense_date) = ym.m
             LEFT JOIN user_report_categories urc
               ON    urc.id = ure.user_category_id
           WHERE urc.user_id = 48
             AND urc.report_type = 'expense'
           GROUP BY y, m
       ) t
```

Comment: That kicked me off in the right direction, I tweaked it a bit and got it working now, thank you!